# How can I fix broken highlighting settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, syntax-highlighting

SCSS highlighting for some properties are highlighted as if they are selectors. I'm looking for settings to adjust or a plugin that will fix the highlighting as it's distracting.

How VSC displays:

[image: How VSC displays],

how the same code looks in Sublime Text 3:

[image: how the same code looks in Sublime Text 3]

Comment: What's the file's suffix?

Comment: @connexo the suffix is .scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Grant developed a patch which fixes this problem perfectly. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cssinate.scss-language-improvements